# Retrieving row from gridview data or mySQL DB and display in PopUp

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

[image: Current Grid View structure with View Anchor - I want to view a specific row after clicking on View anchor, data should be displayed in popup - javascript]

Current Grid View structure with View Anchor - I want to view a specific row after clicking on View anchor, data should be displayed in popup - javascript

Below is my code. I have already implemented functionality for PHP Grid View, Delete option is implemented at the top with querystring

Now what i want is, After clicking view, it should display javascript popup with all the details of that specific row, and close option

The part which am not getting is
how to transfer data from php/mysql to javaScript and display it in popup
`

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    //$x = 'confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this product")';
    //echo $x;
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '$id'");
    //echo "alert('Row Deletion Successful')";
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Table Display</title>

    <style>
table, td, th
{
border:1px solid green;
}
th
{
background-color:green;
color:white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, CONCAT(title, ' ',  name) as FullName, email, mobile FROM users") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $row_count = 1;
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            echo '<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>';
            echo "<th> Sr. No </th>";
            foreach($row as $col=>$value)
            {

                echo "<th>";
                echo $col;
                echo "</th>";

            }
            ?>
            <th>EDIT</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php 
mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>';
    echo "<td>" . $row_count ."</td>";

    foreach($row as $key=>$value)
    {

    echo "<td>";
    echo $row[$key];
    echo "</td>";
}
    $row_count++;
    ?>

    <td>
            <a href="users.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this product ?')" title="VIEW" class="icon-1 info-tooltip">VIEW | </a>
            <a href="users.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this product ?')" name="delete">DELETE |</a>
            <a href="users.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" title="EDIT" class="icon-5 strong-text info-tooltip">EDIT </a>
        </td>

    <?php


    echo "</tr>";
}   

echo "</table>";


?>


    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this code to display in your records in popup window

```
 function openWin()
{
 myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
 myWindow.document.write("<p>your code to display in table format</p>");
 myWindow.focus();
}
<a onclick="openWin();">Edit/Delete/View(any one)</a>
```

try this out in document.write() method enter your code inside a table tag

Answer (score 0):

render specific view in a page (e.g. viewpageaddress.php?id=7)
and then get it's content in js by:

```
$.get('viewpageaddress.php?id=7', function(cnt){/* show cnt in your popup */})
```